# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate filtering

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to prevent a user from creating a new insert if the new schedule start date is in between already scheduled dates. For example, an employee id 123 has already applied for a leave from 2021-04-05 to 2021-04-09, I must prevent the user from applying again if the start date is in the range from 2021-04-05 to 2021-04-09.

Here is my model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const {ObjectID} = mongoose.Schema.Types;

const ScheduleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    startdate: {type: Date},
    enddate: {type: Date},
    dateadded: {type: Date,default: Date.now},
    userid:[{type:ObjectID, ref:"User"}],
  },{ timestamps: true });
  
  module.exports = mongoose.model("Schedule", ScheduleSchema)
  const Schedule = require('../models/schedules')
```

And here is my code which I am stuck here using the findOneAndUpdate and of course it didn't work:

```
router.post('/schedule/addschedule/:id',JWTAuthenticatToken, async (req, res) => {   
   const{startdate,enddate} = req.body
   const existingSchedule = await CourseSchedule.findOneAndUpdate({startdate: startdate,enddate:enddate,course:req.params.id},{startdate: startdate,enddate:enddate,course:req.params.id},{ new: true, upsert: true })
   return res.json(existingSchedule);       
});
```

How should I do it? Many thanks in advance and appreciate any helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally able to get it working. Here is the answer and I hope it is useful here.

```
  const existingSchedule = await Schedule.findOne({$and:[{startdate:{$lte:startdate}},{enddate:{$gte:startdate}},{userid:req.params.id}]})
```